# Is it possible to switch the ContentAreaRenderer dynamically based on multisite in Optimizely/Episerver?

Tags: episerver, optimizely

Is it possible to switch the ContentAreaRenderer dynamically based on multisite in Optimizely/Episerver? Some of our sites use the EpiBoostrapArea nuget package and some have their custom content area renderer previously when they were not in a multisite env. We are moving all these sites to a multisite env and the issue is realted to that. Any code samples would be appreciated. Episerver  v11

Thanks in advance
M

Comment: Perhaps use the same `ContentAreaRenderer` type for all content areas, but have it use a site-specific `ContentAreaRenderer` type depending on the current context/site?

Comment: Thanks Ted. Yes after spending so much time trying different things, I think this is the way to go. Thanks again.